# bootstrap nav header height

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nav

How to make the height of all names of the tabs same size?
At LI the height is same, but if I do for A height: 100% nothing changes.
Thanks

```
simple bootstrap
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/SeaBJ/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var highest = null;

   $(".nav-tabs a").each(function(){  //find the height of your highest link
       var h = $(this).height();
       if(h > highest){
          highest = $(this).height();  
       }    
    });

   $(".nav-tabs a").height(highest);  //set all your links to that height.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wW2py/9/

For CSS you can do

```
.nav-tabs a {
   height: 62px;  
}
```

For your example 62px works, but you'll need to adjust it so that it is big enough to fit the tab with the most text.
Also make sure you apply your css after the bootstrap css.

http://jsfiddle.net/p9eFQ/

Comment: Thanks, but and no way using CSS?

Comment: @MishaKondratev please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks